# Howto apply alpha value (Color) to a sprite in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, alpha-blending

Howto apply alpha to a sprite so it will work.

With the following code, the sprite still is completely visible.

Can someone help me ?

```
batch.enableBlending();
if (sprite != null) {
    Color c = sprite.getColor();
        c.a = 0;
        sprite.setColor(c);
}
batch.draw(sprite, x, y);
sprite.setAlpha(0f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're drawing the sprite the wrong way:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); // Clear the screen with black
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear the screen

batch.enableBlending(); // Enable alpha
batch.begin();

sprite.setAlpha(0);
sprite.draw(batch); // This is how you should draw a sprite. 

batch.end();
batch.disableBlending();
```

This works fine for me.